# Set ClientId using GTM on a site with analytics.js snippet?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is it possible to set GA ClientID to a custom dimension using GTM (Google Tag Manager) on a site that already uses analytics.js snippet?

I have an existing analytics.js snippet on a site and I can not edit this existing tag in any way. I can only add new GTM tags. I want to start pushing the clientId to a custom dimension. Is this possible?

Will creating a new GTM pageview tag (with exact same tracker name and domain as anayltics.js tag) override the pageview pushed by the analytics.js snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a Google Analytics event (non-interaction) via GTM with custom dimension to the same property.

Sending a second pageview you will have 2 pageviews.

Comment: Will sending a new event link the clientid custom dimension to the pageview that was sent by analytics.js?

Comment: Yes send it with tag Google Analytics: Universal Analytics, if client id is a user level it will be associated with the current session.